# Regular Expression: Searching the pattern "(space)word(space)" (Vb.net)

Tags: regex, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I am trying creating a MS-Access database programmatically from Sqlite sentences in Visual Basic 2008, and as word "password" is a field reserved word, I have to replace it by "[password]" and it works fine. The problem is, there is field names with "password" word embedded as "2nd_password" or "password_3rd" for example, in this case doesn't necessary replace "password"

So I am searching the following results:

```
 password -> [password]
 2nd_password -> 2nd_password
 password_3rd -> password_3rd
```

I've tried searching the pattern "(space)password(space)" but it doesn't work.

```
 Regex.Replace(query, ":bpassword:b", " [password] ")
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match-vbnet) it seems like in VB you still use `\b` not `:b`

```
 Regex.Replace(query, "\bpassword\b", " [password] ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one as well apart from `\b`:

```
(?<!\w)password(?!\w)
```

Thins one is checking a non alphanumeric(`a-z A-Z 0-9 _`) characters on left and right side of the `password`.